# Xamarin forms IOS app crashing on launch on iPad, can't reproduce

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

App store review is constantly rejecting my app saying it's crashing on the launch on the iPad (15.5).

The app runs fine on the iPad on the simulator (both debug and release version). I could not reproduce the issue but Apple is rejecting it saying the splash screen is displayed for 20 seconds and the app crashes.

Is anybody else having the same issue lately?

I am running xamarin.forms 5.0.0.2478 (the latest version at this time) and the latest version of visual studio.

Any idea on how to reproduce this issue locally?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is not programming related

Comment: Have you tested on a physical iPad?  That seems like the first thing to dry.  Have you examined the crash log from Apple?  Have you tried instrumenting your app to gather info on crashes?

Comment: @Jason I do not have an Ipad. I only have an iPhone and it's working fine on the iPhone. I did examine the crash log and the bug is '309'. How do I instrument a xamarin forms app?

Comment: Find someone who has an iPad and borrow it.  For instrumentation, raygun.io, appcenter.ms, etc

Comment: @drum - if it was rejected for a different reason, it might not be a question for SO, but the crash itself is clearly “programming related”.

Comment: Given that it works on emulator, its related to timing of something you are doing while displaying the first page. *Maybe* can be avoided by having first xamarin page be a simple page, during which you run whatever startup code you have. Then navigate to the "real" page you wish to show.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have successfully submitted this app for 4 different client already over the last year. Strangely, this time it’s being rejected. App.xaml.cs file is identical and hasn’t changed between this version and others that were successfully accepted. 
If it’s crashing for an iPad then you would think that it will crash for iPhone too but it’s not crashing on iPhone. Feels like there’s a bug in xamarin.ios latest version. 

I am waiting to find an iPad to test it.

Comment: *"If it’s crashing for an iPad then you would think that it will crash for iPhone too but it’s not crashing on iPhone."* Not necessarily. iPadOS has some internal differences. (Though doesn't explain why crashes on real device and not emulator.) And unless those other apps were quite recent, there could also be OS updates that affect something. But if you were (now) getting iPad crashes on the other apps, that would be visible in Apple crash logs - do you have access to those for the previous clients' apps?

Comment: *"App.xaml.cs file is identical"*: If App.xaml was the issue, I'd expect to also see problem on emulator or other devices. Its more likely some interaction between display of first page, and whatever startup code your app needs (for third-party libraries, and your own purposes.)

Comment: BTW, you do know what 309 error means, right? That's why I always start an X-Forms app on a simple page: To be sure the app gets past that iOS startup timeout, regardless of quality of iOS device, or unusual circumstances (e.g. slow "first response" by networking or gps or internet timeout or nearly full storage + fragmented device memory because user hasn't powered off their device in a very long time).

Comment: I bet when you try it on a newly powered-up iPad, it will work just fine. If so, Then the fix is to change the sequence in which you run startup code and/or change what code has to run for the first page to appear, so that the first page comes up ASAP. Then you have a good time buffer, for poor circumstances. Non-Xamarin-Forms apps typically don't have a problem (unless very badly written), because a lot less needs to happen before the first page is shown.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes, lately I see many crashes on my old apps in the App Analytics section. I could not replicate this crash and the client hasn't reported it yet. I will try your suggestion of redirecting to a simple page first and then show the real page after couple of API calls.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I am using TinyIOC for dependency Injection and looks like this is slowing the app launch time.

Comment: IIRC, at startup, TinyIOC uses reflection to enumerate all the view and viewmodel classes, to prepare dependency injection. An app with more pages will take longer. But I wouldn't expect that to be long enough to be an issue. Do any of your views or viewmodels have `static` code that runs when the class is first referenced? This would either be a `static constructor`: `static MyClassName(){ // code that runs one time for this class ...`. or a slow `static field initializer`: `static SomeType MyStaticField = SlowInitializationFunction();`?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I submitted another version of the app that uses a plain page as a landing transition and redirects to the main page afterwards and it was rejected too. On further investigation, I found out the issue was the client's domain itself. It was set up to block requests outside of Australia. This explains why the Apple test is crashing and not mine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: ouch! A challenging issue to unravel. Glad you solved it.